# unable to connect to webserver from LAN (access from outside is fine)

Tags: firewall, nat, zywall

We would like to give both our customers and coworkers a single link (subdomain.ourdomain.com) to access a common web application.

I set up a web server on a machine connected to LAN, it's accessible from any workstation inside our LAN using its ip. I then installed a firewall (Zyxel USG20) with appropriate firewall rules and port forwarding and everything worked fine, except for accessing the web server using the public ip.

He's the configuration

- all workstations + the server's first ethernet adapter are on LAN (all connected to a switch, which is connected to the firewall's LAN1 port)
- The Web server has two network adapters, the first one is connected to LAN and the second one to the firewall's DMZ port.
- I set up a NAT rule to redirect traffic from the firewall's WAN port to the web server's second Ethernet interface (connected to the firewall's DMZ port) for HTTP

**Mapping type:Virtual Server | Interface:Wan1 | Original IP:any | Mapped IP: | Protocol:tcp | original port:http | Mapped port:http**

My web server is accessible from outside our LAN using our public ip and subdomain.ourdomain.com, but not from the LAN using our public IP (nor using the domain name address). I then added another rule

**Mapping type:Virtual Server | Interface:Wan1 | Original IP: | Mapped IP: | Protocol:tcp | original port:http | Mapped port:http**

this, with the option "Enable NAT Loopback" checked.

But it didn't help either, I keep having the server timeout page.

What did I miss exactly ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I just recently got a USG100 which is pretty much same and I was struggling with the LAN -> Server connection, so here is what i did to get it working for me.

1. Created **Object / Address** for the server.
2. Add **Service** if needed, I used HTTP/HTTPS in my case but tested
   with custom one succesfully.
3. Created **NAT** rules using **public ip** address as original ip and NAT
   loopback enabled.
4. Added **Firewall** rules to allow the traffic.

[NAT rules screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFifO.jpg)

Hope this solves the problem for you also.

Comment: Hey, I've just read your message. thanks a lot :-)